# R if statement incorrectly passes when function used in a tibble

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have confused about this for the past hour and may someone help me out.

Here is my code, where I attempt to create 2 functions that are to be used in a tibble().
[image]

```
n <- 1000
w <- function(x) {
  if(-2 <= x & x <= 2) {
    return((-3/32)*x^2 + 3/8)
  }else{
    return(0)
  }
}
y <- function(x){
  if(0 <= x & x <= 8){
    return((1/8)*x^(-2/3) - (1/32))
  }else{
    return(0)
  }
}
df <- tibble(value = seq(2, 9, length.out = n), W = w(value), Y = y(value))
head(df)
```

As you see, W returns a negative value when values are greater than 2, but in my function w(), there is an if statement to restrict that from happening.

So what's going and how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Only the first item in your sequence satisfies both of the logical conditions, so you get exactly one 0 from the `w` function. I show you how to fix teh original syntactic error below but I'm guessing the problem is more of a semantic problem in your head.

Comment: why having negative value in `w` is a problem? You said you want to have value in `w` between -2 and 2. Those values in `w` are in those range.

Comment: Do NOT use `return` this way.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `if`/`else` which works for single input (scalar) and you are passing multiple values to it (vector). You should use `ifelse` which is vectorised.

IfI have understood you correctly in `w` you want to apply the formula `(-3/32)*x^2 + 3/8` but if a value is negative assign as 0. Same for `y` where you want to apply formula `(1/8)*x^(-2/3) - (1/32)`. You can change your function to.

```
w <- function(x) {
  pmax((-3/32)*x^2 + 3/8, 0)
}

y <- function(x){
  pmax((1/8)*x^(-2/3) - (1/32), 0)
}

df <- tibble(value = seq(2, 9, length.out = n), W = w(value), Y = y(value))
head(df)
```

`pmax` selects maximum of both the inputs passed. For example,

```
pmax(-5:5, 0)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Hey man, I recognized the problem in the use of the if/else and finally did use ifelse(), but I want to produce values that are between -2 and 2, and not only the positive values as pmax() i assume is used for, I used the between(n, -2, 2) yet it still didn't produce a 0 when its outside -2 and 2.

Comment: So for `w` you want to apply the formula `(-3/32)*x^2 + 3/8` and keep only the values between -2 and 2 and turn rest of them to 0?

Comment: yes, I have looked at the documentation of the between() and since my sequence vector has no value of -2 or 2, for which I assume it rounds. But yet, when viewing my data frame, there still exist values for inputs that are outside of the -2 and 2

Comment: @AntonyD : Puzzled. Your first item in `df$value` is 2. AND `(-3/32)*2^2 + 3/8` is also 0. So for that case teh ifelse decsions is really moot. Not sure which part of your dataframe is of concern to you. Please be more specific in your statement of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that does what you want to a much smaller test case that still allows looking across the full extent of the ranges of you values (I took the liberty of expanding the range of testing for values because the original case where x was between -2 and 2 had only one instance and that gave 0 for w(2) regardless.

```
n <- 10
w <- function(x) {
    ifelse( -2 <= x & x <= 3 , (-3/32)*x^2 + 3/8, 0) 
                 }
y <- function(x){
    ifelse (0 <= x & x <= 8, (1/8)*x^(-2/3) - (1/32), 0)
                  }
df <- tibble(value = seq(2, 9, length.out = n), W = w(value), Y = y(value))
#-----------

df
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   value      W       Y
   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  2     0     0.0475 
 2  2.78 -0.348 0.0320 
 3  3.56  0     0.0224 
 4  4.33  0     0.0158 
 5  5.11  0     0.0109 
 6  5.89  0     0.00708
 7  6.67  0     0.00404
 8  7.44  0     0.00154
 9  8.22  0     0      
10  9     0     0
```

---

Earlier observations:
Your code threw an error and I addressed it by making a couple of minor adjustments to the `w` function:

```
w <- function(x) {
    if( (-2 <= x) && (x <= 2)) {
        (-3/32)*x^2 + 3/8)
    } else { 0   }
}
```

I think the use of ‘return’ might have been causing problems.

The expression in your first version threw this error:

```
Error: unexpected '<=' in:
"w <- function(x) {
    if(-2 <= x <="
```

... because the mathematically sensible `-2 <= x <= 2` just isn't parse-worthy in R.

Comment: I used the ifelse(between(x, -2, 2), return((-3/32)*x^2 + 3/8), return(0)) and ti did work but for some reason, it would still produce values outside of 2 and -2 when it should be failing the condition and just returning a 0

Comment: I doubt that it would be correct to use ‘return’ in either the second or third arguments to ‘ifelse’